# Is there a SyndicationFeed class for Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

Is there a `SyndicationFeed` class available for Windows Phone? The original lives in `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` namespace and then there is a new one for Windows 8 in `Windows.Web.Syndication` namespace. However, I don't see it on the phone.

Comment: You can use xml parsers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is available in library: **System.ServiceModel.Syndication.dll** for Silverlight 4.0, that can be referenced in WP7 projects (not sure about WP8), but it's quite different from the implementation in WinRT.

Comment: This works great for me. The SL4 assembly ends up in my XAP file and works as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I found the DLL in this folder...

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client

Answer (score 1):

that dll is not available for WP8